# Css animation not keeping at the latest position

Tags: css, css-animations

Hi I've been learning css for 2 months , so i met a problem with animation .
I want my code to finish at lime , but animation finishes , and div again becomes red.

```
    @keyframes example{
        from{background-color: red}
        to{background-color: lime}
    }


    .animate{
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        background-color: red;
        animation-name: example;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've done this to your code .

```
    @keyframes example{
        from{background-color: red}
        to{background-color: lime}
    }


    .animate{
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        background-color: red;
        animation-name: example;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the background-color from red to lime.

```css
@keyframes example{
  from{background-color: red}
  to{background-color: lime}
}

.animate{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: lime;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate"></div>
```